# Functions of continuous random variables and finding of k values in valid PDF

Tags: probability, statistics

The major issue of this problem is relating to finding k values, then the others is quite straight forward.

Assume
$$ f_{X}(x)=kx+1/2 \quad for -1\leqslant x\leqslant1 $$
and zero otherwise, $k$ is constant.

The questions:
What is the value of $k$ so that $ f_{X}(x)$ is valid PDF.
And then find E(X) and var(X).
Finally find the values of $k$ that can maximize the var(X).

My attempt:
For the first question, should the value of $k$ become 1 or any real number? As the integration from -1 to 1 gives 1. This look weird when I set up the equation and then I have 1 = k1.

For the seconds question, I used $k$ equal to 1 and find that the $E(X) is 2/3. Also the var(x) is -1/9.

For the final one, we just differentiate the Var(X) with respect to k (which equal to 0) and set derivative equal to zero. Therefore, when k=1, it maximizes the var(X).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be a proper PDF, $f_X$ has to integrate to 1 and be non-negative.

The first condition is satisfied for all $k$. Indeed

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} kx+\frac{1}{2} \, dx = \frac{kx^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2} \bigg|_{-1}^{1}= 1, \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Instead $f_X \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow k \le 1/2$

With the PDF we can compute the required quantities using the definition:

$$
\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_{-1}^{1}kx^2+\frac{x}{2} \, dx = \frac{2}{3}k \\
S:= \text{Var}(X) = \int_{-1}^{1}kx^3+\frac{x^2}{2} \, dx - \frac{4}{9}k^2 = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{4}{9}k^2
$$

Finally

$$
\frac{dS}{dk}= - \frac{8}{9}k > 0 \Leftrightarrow k < 0
$$

Hence $k=0$ maximazes the variance.

Just a remark: your computations could not be correct, at least the one for the variance because it is *always* a positive quantity so $-1/9$ had to be wrong.

Comment: I agree that the value of $k$ is smaller than 1/2. Does it also has the bounding on the other side, which is -1/2 to 1/2?

Comment: You are correct. we also need the other bound